# how to click a link using selenium driver in python while don't know the text inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, xpath

I use `selenium+phantomJS+scrapy` to scrapy javascript content. And i want to click a link in the table after loading the javascript content. But the most important thing is that with different input content, the link i want to click changed.

then i want to use xpath to locate the link but i failed. Here's the html element and the xpath i wrote.

```
<div class="results searchResults" style="display: block;”>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="resultGroup">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="4.216%">
            <col width="43.13%">
            <col width="52.65%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="selector">
                    <a href="#" id="c_2441797" title="Apple Inc." class="checkbox unchecked">&nbsp;</a>
                </td>
                <td class="name">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#!search/profile/company?companyId=2441797&amp;targetid=profile" class="companyResultsName">Apple Inc.</a>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com/finance?client=ob&amp;q=NASDAQ: AAPL" rel="external" target="_blank">(NASDAQ: AAPL)</a>
                    </div>
```

the xpath is `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='resultGroup']/tbody/tr[@class='name']/div[1]/a[@class='companyResultsName']").click()`

hope someone could give me a hint.  Thanks.

Comment: can you add `html` rather then image. Your `xpath` seems incorrect.

Comment: try xpath `//a[@class='companyResultsName'][contains(text(),'Apple Inc.')]`

Comment: @Narendra Rajput i have changed the photo to `html`

Comment: @NarendraRajput i tried your xpath, but the terminal output errors `NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//a[@class='companyResultsName'][contains(text(),'Apple Inc.')]'",`

Comment: make sure your element is not under `iframe` if it is then you have to switch into frame. if not then use `explicit wait`  conditions

Comment: @NarendraRajput yes man. The element is not under iframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133620/discussion-between-narendra-rajput-and-peter-tsung).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element is dynamically generated by `JavaScript`, you should wait until it present in `DOM`:

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "companyResultsName")))
 link.click()
```

Comment: man! You are just amazing! I don't know why i follow your suggestion and then i could click the link! Thank you so much. By the way, if i want to click the second link which with the same class, how should i do?